# How to increase pie size in pChart

Tags: php, pchart

The method draw3DPie only allow me to position the graph, not to define the size. 
If I define a bigger image (pImage) only the background of the chart is increased. 
How can I get a bigger pie?

Answer (score 3):

```
$PieChart->draw3DPie(150,100,
                   array("Radius"=>80,
                  "DrawLabels"=>TRUE,"DataGapAngle"=>10,
                  "DataGapRadius"=>6,"Border"=>TRUE));

"Radius"=>80
```

change number to adjust the size

credit goes to stlfan

Answer (score 0):

First you have to adjust the size of your PImage, then the drawFilledRectangle, then you modify the Radius of your pie chart.

```
//Change the first 2 values: 1024 and 720:

yPicture = new pImage(1024,720,$MyData);

//Then the 700 and 450 values:

$myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(0,0,700,450,$Settings);

//Then:

$PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData);


 $PieChart->draw3DPie(350,200,array("Radius"=>140,"DrawLabels"=>TRUE,"LabelStacked"=>TRUE,"Border"=>TRUE));

//Then the 350 and 200 are the position in the screen, the radius is the size of the pie.
```